# Gauss-Bonnet topological invariant at linear order

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus, gauss-bonnet

I have a question about the Gauss-Bonnet invariant $T$,
\begin{equation}
T=R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}-4R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}+R^2
\end{equation}
It is known that $T$ is a topological invariant, which implies that it's an intrinsic property and does not contribute to the field equations in an least action principle.

My question is, since $T$ is a topological invariant, one should be able to proof the following,
\begin{equation}
\delta S= \int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \delta T = \int d^4x \sqrt{-g} \delta \left( R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}-4R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}+R^2\right)
=0
\end{equation}
Right? Even more, by the same reason, this variation could be calculated with the linear expressions of the Riemann tensor, Ricci tensor and Ricci scalar. Is there something wrong in this argument? If not, I have tried to proof it using the linear expresions:
\begin{equation}
R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\partial_\sigma\partial_\nu h_{\rho\mu}-\partial_\sigma\partial_\mu h_{\nu\rho} - \partial_\rho\partial_\nu h_{\sigma\mu}+\partial_\rho\partial_\mu h_{\nu\sigma} \right)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
R_{\nu\sigma} = \eta^{\mu\rho}R_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} = \dfrac{1}{2}\Big(\partial_\sigma\partial_\nu h_{\mu}^{\mu}-\partial_\sigma\partial_\mu h_{\nu}^\mu - \partial_\rho\partial_\nu h_{\sigma}^\rho+\square^2 h_{\nu\sigma}\Big)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
R =\square^2 h_{\mu}^\mu - \partial_\mu \partial_\nu h^{\mu\nu}
\end{equation}
But there are no nice simplifications in the algebra and it gets really tedious, so I don't know if I'm right.

Comment: You might try using the identity:
$$
R_{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}R^{\mu\nu\alpha\beta}-4R_{\mu\nu}R^{\mu\nu}+R^2 = -\frac{|g|}{4}\epsilon_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}\epsilon^{\alpha\beta\gamma\delta}R_{\alpha\beta}^{~~\mu\nu}R_{\gamma\delta}^{~~\rho\sigma}
$$

Comment: But my attempt is correct? Also, it would be nice if you could give me some reference to that formula you wrote. Thanks.